# Show that $ \int_{a}^{b} (\int_x^{b} f(t)dt)dx = \int_a^b (x-a)f(x)dx $ by using intuition

Tags: calculus

$$  \int_{a}^{b} \left(\int_x^{b} f(t)dt\right)dx = \int_a^b (x-a)f(x)dx $$
I already know the proof of the equation that use substitution and integration by parts.

But I want to know the solution to use graph and intuition. Is there any intuitive proof of this equation?

Comment: You have proof by contradiction, proof by induction etc, but nothing called proof by intuition :-)

Comment: Can you show that $F(b)-F(x)=(x-a)*f(x)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically integrating $f(t)$ over the region $R=\{(x,t): x\leq t \leq b,\, a\leq x\leq b\},$ which is a triangle (draw a picture on the $xt$ plane. The left hand side is the integration order $dtdx$.

If you take the same region, and integrate under the order $dxdt$, you will obtain the right hand side of the equation after the initial $dx$ integral.

It's probably easier to see if on the right hand side, you make a trivial change of notation and write
$$
\int_a^b (x-a)f(x)dx=\int_a^b (t-a)f(t)dt.
$$